# Seeking advice on using/attaching View displays for my Nodequeue collections

Tags: views, 6, panels, nodes

On my organization's Drupal 6 site, we use Nodequeue to curate "collections" of content, modeled somewhat after the functionality of scoop.it. Nodequeue fails to provide any information *about* the queues, so I created a content type called Collection that has a field in which the author can enter the number of the queue to be displayed with the description and metadata of the collection node.

The default view of a collection is a nicely visual tile view (again, similar to scoop.it) but I also developed a list view with exposed filters which makes the collections much more interesting and useful for people browsing them. In a previous version of this feature, I based the view on the URL argument and required the collection node and the queue to have the exact same name the argument would be the same. However, some names could not translate to URLs that would feed back correctly into views, so I changed to using the custom field with queue ID and used the "node content" view display type to attach the tiled collection to the node.

The problem with this approach is I can't figure out how to let the user also see the list view. I tried making it an additional "node content" display in the view, but then they both show up. I tried the QuickTabs module for switching, but it doesn't pull in the view at all.

I feel like I'm very close to getting this to work, but I am just missing one crucial piece of understanding about arguments in Views. I'm also using Panels because they are already used for displaying nodes with different variants for different content types. If it helps, the collections can be viewed at http://www.hastac.org/collections and I'm attaching a screenshot of my view.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Looks like [Viewfield](http://drupal.org/project/viewfield) module might be what you need. But I must admit that reading the whole story somewhat obscured what's your current state of development and what's your need. If it's possible, could you try to make it simpler by removing parts not directly related to your actual problem? And don't forget that images here are at 930px width max. It's really hard to read to me.

Comment: Thanks, that's good advice. Let  me try to simplify: I want to display a node (type=collection) with two different views attached so that a user can switch between them (tile view and list/filter view). The argument to the view needs to be sent from a custom field on the node.  But I'm also open to other ways to arrange this.